Wordpress: Uncaught TypeError: _.all is not a function in admin media-model.min.js
My media library in the admin area isn’t working after a content import.
I’m getting the following error – Uncaught TypeError: _.all is not a function
This error is coming from the file media-model.min.js. As far as I see, the problem is _.all is an Underscore.js method, but at this point of call _ is assigned as lodash and _.all in undefined.
I believe lodash is being instantiated correctly using window.lodash = _.noConflict() in the script-loader.php file.

I have run a diff to confirm that there are no differences between a downloaded WordPress and the one installed on the site.
I have removed all plugins.
I have checked that there are no file modifications in the theme

I’m not a WordPress developer, so there’s likely something I’m missing. Is it possible there is something changing script load order in the database? Anything else I might want to check? Thanks
